# How to update properties file using ConfigObj

Tags: python, configobj

Is their any way for updating value of a key in properties file using ConfigObj in python.

Before updating properties file:

```
hostKey = "value"
```

After updating properties file:

```
hostKey = "updatedValue"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ConfigObj Documentation

> Creating a new config file is just as easy as reading one. You can
>   specify a filename when you create the ConfigObj, or do it later [2].
>
> If you don’t set a filename, then the write method will return a list
>   of lines instead of writing to file. See the write method for more
>   details.
>
> Here we show creating an empty ConfigObj, setting a filename and some
>   values, and then writing to file :

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj("test.config")
config.filename ="test.config"
config['keyword1'] = "value6"
config['keyword2'] = "value2"
config.write()
```

I think similar way u can read and set to the same file name and then over-write the property you want.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't updates key value pair with this logic.

Comment: One more clarification, I am opening file in append mode that's why it doesn't overwrites.

Comment: I have update the code a bit , i dont think u need `config.filename` line but it should work .

Answer (score 2):

This should help.

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj("FileName")

print(config['hostKey'])
config['hostKey'] = "updatedValue"        #Update Key
config.write()                            #Write Content
print(config['hostKey'])                  #Check Updated value.
```